# How do I fix Truffle deployment not working on struct array: "components found but type is not tuple; report on GitHub."?

Tags: solidity, truffle

I wrote the following, which compiles in truffle just fine, but will not deploy. I get the error "components found but type is not tuple; report on GitHub." Am I doing something wrong appending to a struct array?

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

contract Sandbox {

  struct Leader {
    address host;
    uint fitness;
  }

  Leader[] public myList;

  function append(uint value) public {
    Leader memory leader = Leader(msg.sender, value);
    myList.push(leader);
  }

}
```

Comment: This error is most likely not related to this contract but to something else within your system.

Comment: @goodvibration Thanks, deleting the contract and recompiling and then creating the contract again seems to have fixed it.

Comment: sometimes, you may have to clear your build folder before migrations or testing using truffle.